# Accessing resources from code for setting NotifyIcon.Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource, notifyicon

I am trying to get the Icon of a `NotifyIcon` in WPF.

So I have added a `.ico` file to my solution in a `Resources` folder and set the build action to `Resource`.

I am trying to grab this resource in code behind like so:

`var icon = (Icon) Application.Current.FindResource("/Resources/icon.ico")`

This doesn't work.

In addition to this: `Application.Current.Resources.Count` returns `0`.

**EDIT**

`var i = new Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/systemtrayicon.ico", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);`

With the icon in the root and the build action set to `Resource`.

Still not working.

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I needed to Clean the solution and rebuild as per: [WPF throws "Cannot locate resource" exception when loading the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948829/wpf-throws-cannot-locate-resource-exception-when-loading-the-image)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to pass resourceName as a parameter to the FindResource method, not the path for the Resource. Sample code would look like:

```
var icon = (Icon) Application.Current.FindResource("myImage")
```

Please note in the above sample code "myImage" is the resource name.

Refer to [Application.FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method on MSDN.

You say, Application.Current.Resources.Count is Zero, that means you do not have any Resource defined in your App.xaml file.

You can add resources to App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
     <Image x:Key="myImage" Source="img.png" />
</Application.Resources>
```

It appears that your icon is an embedded resource. `FindResource` cannot work with embedded resources. Set `BuildAction` of your icon to `Resource`.

Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742538%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN page for more reading on WPF Resources.

**UPDATE**

Code for accessing Embedded Resources

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("myImg.png");
```

However, if you had added this image to the Resources.Resx and you should simply be able to use `Resources.ResourceName`.

**UPDATE 2**

Adding resources to App.xaml or any ResourceDictionary is better, so that you can use them as Static/Dynamic resources via `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` markup extensions.

If you do not want to add it to App.xaml resources and still want to access it, one option as I mentioned above is to add it to the `Resources.Resx` and use `Resources.ResourceName` to refer the icon/image

Another way is to create `System.Drawing.Icon` by yourself, sample code:

```
new System.Drawing.Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Resources/icon.ico")));
```

Personally, I would go with XAML resources and add them to App.xaml or a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: So how would I reference the `.ico` file from code WITHOUT adding them to the `App.xaml` file. Or must all resources be accessed or specified within XAML?

Comment: No, you don't have to. But preferred approach for WPF/XAML development. Since in your question you mentioned it is a Resource (not embedded resource) you could try the approach of creating Icon by  yourself by calling `new System.Drawing.Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Resources/icon.ico")));`

Comment: This is something I was already trying before your edit: `new Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/systemtrayicon.ico")).Stream);`. This is with the icon in the root and the Build Action set to `Resource`. Complaining that it can't find the resource.

Comment: Let me try in a sample app

Comment: Tried in a sample app, and it seem to be working. `new System.Drawing.Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("orange.ico", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);`

Comment: I needed to Clean the solution and rebuild as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948829/wpf-throws-cannot-locate-resource-exception-when-loading-the-image

Answer (score 22):

**This will works 100%**

```
ni.Icon = new Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,<Image Location From root>")).Stream);
```

**Example:**

```
notify.Icon = new Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/favicon.ico")).Stream);
```

Comment: thanx, simple and easy