# Loading resource image to NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I'm using WPF and I want to use `NotifyIcon` from WinForms. My icon image is located in `<project_folder>/Resources/icon.ico`. It has `Build action` set to `Resource`. But this code: `this.ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("pack://application:,,,/Resources/icon.ico");` throws me an exception: *The given path's format is not supported.*

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use an icon that is a resource in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466/how-do-i-use-an-icon-that-is-a-resource-in-wpf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing resources from code for setting NotifyIcon.Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374060/accessing-resources-from-code-for-setting-notifyicon-icon)