# IOException : cannot locate resource at Design time only

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, designer, ioexception

I'm having a problem with my designer on a MVVM project.

I have a `TreeView` with a custom `DataTemplate` :

```
                             <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="img"  Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" 
                                       Source="{Binding 
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                       Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                       AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, 
                                       Path=Header, 
                                       Converter={StaticResource HeaderToImageConverter}}"       
                                       />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
```

Resource declaration :

```
<Window x:Class="BlobWorld.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Core="clr-namespace:BlobWorld;assembly=" 
        xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:BlobWorld.Helper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350.459" Width="746.561"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <helper:HeaderToImageConverter x:Key="HeaderToImageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

My Converter is :

```
public class HeaderToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((value as string).Contains(@"."))
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/File.png");
                BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                return source;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(value as string).Contains(@":"))
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/folder.png");
                    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                    return source;
                }
                else
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/diskdrive.png");
                    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                    return source;
                }
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly at run-time, but when I'm using the xaml "design" windows in Visual Studio instead of seeing the appearance of my Windows, I only have a `IOException : Cannot locate resource 'images/folder.png'`

Where is my problem coming from ?
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Probably the easiest fix is to [detect design mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/834332/1997232) in converter and don't try to resolve image in such case (return `null`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11948876/3955716

Comment: @Sinatr if works okayish, I now see my Windows, but (as I return null ...) I don't see my images so it's still annoying to have an idea of my rendering.
If you have a way to return my Images in the code specific to the design mode, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Rom Already done.

Comment: Ok I am having the same exact issue.  I created a user control with an image, then when I embed the user control in a window, the image resource is not available.  But when I compile and run, it shows perfectly fine.  I think this may be a VS bug which is very annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this was never answered and I had the same exact issue that needed a resolution.  The resolution to this problem is as follows:

Change:

```
pack://application:,,,/path/to/images/mypng.png
```

To:

```
/Project Namespace;component/path/to/images/mypng.png
```

That's it!  Also make sure your that the *Build Action* is set to *Resource* on your images and *Copy to Output Directory* is set to *Do not copy* (since this is a resource there is no need to copy the image to the output directory).  Your control will now show in design mode.

Comment: Works for me, but with no Namespace and Uri as "UriKind.Relative":
_new Uri("/MyProject;component/path/to/images/mypng.png", UriKind.Relative)_

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is running on DesignMode or not as follows;

```
    public class HeaderToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
            if (!designMode)
            {
                if ((value as string).Contains(@"."))
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/File.png");
                    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                    return source;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(value as string).Contains(@":"))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/folder.png");
                        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                        return source;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/diskdrive.png");
                        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                        return source;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
        }
    }
```