# 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' exception

Tags: wpf, markup-extensions, baml2006reader

I am using this to display a gif in my app:

```
<Image Height="30" Width="30" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="pack://application:,,,/OffPo diagnostic tool;component/resources/c1.gif" Grid.Column="1" Margin="394,110,42,22" Grid.Row="1" />
```

And it throws me this error :

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.

My resource path is okay, even it shows the image in design time but fails to compile... What's wrong ?

**SEMI-FIX**

I used the exact path as the source:

```
C:\Users\nabil\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OffPo Diagnostic Tool\OffPo Diagnostic Tool\resources\c1.gif
```

This fixed the problem but what if I move my application? Then the problem would occur again. Any permanent fix?

**THIS IS WHAT I FOUND WHEN I TRIED `INNEREXCEPTION`**

[image]

Comment: Do we need to worry about the `<xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com">` part or is it only pseudo-code to define the source of `gif:ImageBehavior`? Same for the `<Grid>` and `</grid>`, I hope that's not your real code?

Comment: yeah , it's kindda copied..anyway, how do i fix the error ?? plese read my edit and give me a solution

Comment: Well, I may look at it again when the mentioned problems are fixed (otherwise the answer would be "can't reproduce", because for example `</grid>` with lower case G doesn't match `<Grid>` and giving a different error than yours) Also please describe how exactly is your image configured as resource?

Comment: Okey now ?.....

Comment: What if you use a relative path like Source="resources/c1.gif" ?

Comment: You should inspect the `InnerException` of that exception in Debugger. You can see the *real* exception reason in that inner exception. I'm pretty sure you have forgotten to set your image file to a `Resource`, so it is not embedded in the application resources.

Comment: if thats the reason then why does it work if i use full file path?

Comment: @dymanoid i added the image in the resources properly, and using `resources\imagename` also gives the same exception ....any help ??

Comment: Please re-read my post

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself...Or should i say SO saved my day again ??

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948829/wpf-throws-cannot-locate-resource-exception-when-loading-the-image)

All i had to do is, select the image from the Solution explorer>Properties>Build action>changed 'None' to 'Resources'